# Prevent the assignment of full control

Tags: 2010, permissions

Is there any way to allow someone to assign permissions, while preventing them from assigning the Full Control permissions level?

Our organization (site-collection) has multiple sub-organizations (sites).  I want the admins from those sub-organizations to be able to grant permissions.  I do not, however, want them to grant Full Control, as Full Control allows people to create groups, which I don't want them to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Mike OOTB "Full Control" is the only option for modifying permissions. If you don't want to give your user full control, I would suggest maybe creating a custom permission level. I would probably just copy the "Full Control" level and remove the access you don't want them to have.

Comment: I want them to be able to assign permissions.  I just don't want them to be able to assign Full Control.

Comment: Your solution has the same issue as mine.  If they can change permissions, they can grant Full Control to themselves.

Comment: when creating a custom permission level you could uncheck all boxes and then just check "Manage Permissions" which will add the following additional checked box items:  view items, open items, view versions, browse directories, view pages, enumerate permissions, browse user information, open. You must have these in order to work with permissions :)

Comment: I understand that.  That's not the issue I have.  These are mid-level admins.  I do not want them to have the ability to give OTHER people Full Control, but I *DO* want them to be able to manage permissions.